# Rails 3: How do you style will_paginate links?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-3, view, will-paginate

In coding layout is the link styled like

```
<a href="#" class="class1 class2 class3"><span>Previous</span></a>
<a href="#" class="class1 class2 class3"><span>Next</span>
```

I tried to search and I found some possible modifications of a shape of these two links. It's:

```
<div class="pag">
  <%= will_paginate @data, :page_links => false, :next_label => '' %> 
</div>

<div class="pag">
  <%= will_paginate @data, :page_links => false, :previous_label => '' %>
</div>
```

My question: How can I update the second example to the shape of the first example? My problem is those two `span` elements...

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

It's can be very easy - just add html markup for your paginate components to your config/locales/en.yml file
for example:

```
en:
  hello: "Hello world"
  will_paginate:
    previous_label: <span class="glyph glyph-prev"></span>
    next_label: <span class="glyph glyph-next"></span>
```

It's all!

Answer (score 2):

http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2010/8/22/revisited-roll-your-own-pagination-links-with-will_paginate-and-rails-3 You can have your own formatter so you can customize anything you want.

Comment: Thank you for the comment and link. I found this article, but I am not able to edit links by that article.  Therefore I am trying to ask here...

Answer (score 0):

**Wiki**

```
en:
  will_paginate:
    previous_label: "&#8592; Previous"
    next_label: "Next &#8594;"
    page_gap: "&hellip;"
```

https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/I18n#translating-will_paginate-output